# Do we need dark matter and dark energy, if the behaviour of the universe in its initial stages was similar to that of the Sun?

Tags: cosmology, big-bang, dark-matter, cosmic-microwave-background, baryons

According to CMBR the universe was a cloud of plasma and was a perfect black body, $380,\!000$ years after big bang.

But the Sun in our solar system also is in the state of plasma, thus making it a blackbody. So it is possible that the universe in its initial stage also behaved similarly(I.e. radiated the energy produced as a result of fusion reactions during the recombination epoch beyond the boundary of the plasma). And this is the reason we find find less baryonic matter than we should. Thus making the concept of dark matter irrelevant.

Comment: I heard dark matter was invented because modern physics theories didnt create accurate simulations in a computer. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GFxPMMkhHuA

Comment: Black bodies DO radiate; dark matter is not black, because it does not radiate.  Thermodynamic principles require surfaces which absorb (are black) be good radiators of light, which is a feature absent in dark matter.

Comment: Dark matter and dark energy are not the same thing

Comment: I don't see how your conclusions follow from your premises. And that's ignoring that your premises aren't correct. And given how you mix up dark matter and dark energy, not to mention the baryon asymmetry (which has nothing to do with either) I'm quite interested in the way you arrived at your conclusion. How did you come to think that either of these three are in any way related?

Comment: You seem to be mixing up dark matter, dark energy, the baryon asymmetry, and blackbodies (which are almost the exact _opposite_ of dark matter) into one big soup -- it's hard to tell what your logic is.

Comment: @eromod Uh... no offense, that seems to be a near total reversal of what the video actually says. I know that skepticism of dark matter is very popular in popsci these days, but still.

Comment: @Luaan My logic in these statements was: 1. Like the Sun the universe that existed as plasma also radiated energy which was able to escape the boundary of the universe at the time of recombination epoch.    2. This radiation could have had contributions from the fusion reactions occurring during the recombination epoch. Thus leading to decrease in the amount of matter, since some amount of the radiation escaped the boundary of the universe. 3. This might be the actual reason the theoretical and observed values of the mass of universe don't match.

Comment: @Luaan after reading the answer by@Sean E.lake I'm able to realise the true purpose of introducing the concept of dark matter (i.e. More than just to add up the mass that we aren't able to observe.)

Answer (score 13):

Short answer: yes.

You should look in to the history behind the dark matter hypothesis. It started not from the examination of cosmology and the CMB, but from the motion of galaxies in clusters and stars orbiting around galaxies. See, the vast majority of ordinary matter in every galaxy is contained in the gas between the stars, not the stars themselves. Because of that, we can get a decent handle on how much ordinary matter is around by observing that. Tools for this purpose: the 21 cm line of atomic hydrogen, when the gas is cold, as much of it is in spiral galaxies, and looking at the x-ray spectrum when it is exceptionally hot, as it is between galaxies in large clusters.

When we examine the way the parts of galaxies, and the galaxies in clusters, move, they're travelling way too fast. If the mass we can see direct evidence for is all there is, the clusters would not be able to hold on to their hot gas and galaxies, and the galaxies would not hold together, either.

"So what? Maybe the matter is there, it just isn't giving off light." Trouble is, if it were hot enough to be a plasma, and thus lack spectral lines, we could see it directly. If it were too cold to be a plasma, it would block light from galaxies and quasars in the background more in the matter's spectral lines. So whatever is producing this extra gravity has to neither emit nor absorb light in any way we've been able to detect.

It just so happens that adding dark matter (or something very like it) to the cosmology simulations is also essential to explain the CMB data.

Now, you may object that the extra gravity we've observed may have some other source. For instance, maybe Newton's law of gravitation is simply wrong on the scale of galaxies and larger. The trouble that idea runs into is you're no longer able to explain the [bullet cluster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullet_Cluster), where the gas between the galaxies has collided, but the dark matter and galaxies did not.

On the subject of black body spectra. The black body is the spectrum that a gas of photons assumes if it is in thermal equilibrium (constant *uniform* temperature everywhere). The CMB is very very nearly a black-body because at the time the differences in temperature between any two parts of the universe were very *very* small. The sun, however, is surrounded by a very cold vacuum, and that lack of equilibrium will inevitably cause the spectrum to deviate from the ideal Planck function.

Comment: Could it be we don’t measure the mass correctly at all?

Comment: @0x90 Not likely. The way we measure mass is based on the physics of how light interacts with matter, something we have measured extremely well here on the ground. See, if a gas is thin enough that it is unlikely to reabsorb anything it emits ("optically thin" - see the 21 cm line), then we can deduce the gas temperature from the way the shape of the line is distorted, and the amount of gas along the line of sight ("column density") from brightness. Total mass is just adding up the lines of sight. The process is similar for absorption, just inverted.

Comment: That said, one of the dark matter candidates is known as "MACHOs" for "Massive Compact Halo Objects". Basically, the thinking is if you have enough really high concentrations of mass that don't emit light (think black holes), that could do the trick. Trouble is, you'd expect them to pass between you and a star from another galaxy from time to time, lensing the light of the background star, making it appear brighter. Searches for this phenomenon have come up short, meaning it is unlikely that MACHOs can explain all of dark matter.

Comment: what if the matter is transparent to light (the wavelength of the light is too long). Like radio wave and our body.

Comment: @0x90 That still leaves the question of what could that matter possibly be. Normal atoms and molecules aren't perfectly transparent - plasma even less so. We see the galaxy illuminated in many wavelengths of light. If there *is* extra mass out there (it's entirely possible there isn't - keep in mind that the calculations are entirely classical, and it's possible e.g. a quantum theory of inertia and/or gravity will correct better than dark matter), it really seems like it doesn't interact with light. That's not really weird on its own - particles don't have to interact electromagnetically.

Comment: Isn't dark matter from the perspective of astronomy just the observation of extra mass, regardless whether the physics explanation is modified gravity, black holes, new particles or whatever? Saying dark matter is WIMPs is a hypothesis, dark matter in itself is not.

Comment: @JollyJoker Dark matter is a hypothesis that lacks some specifics. Dark matter, for example, is not modified gravity. In other words, when we say "dark matter" we really do mean that it is some kind of "matter" - it obeys F=ma, is constructed of particles that have mass, etc. In the language of particle physics, we'd say that dark matter is composed of excitations in some field (probably fermionic). Modifed gravity, on the other hand, is a change to how the gravitational field behaves, no other fields involved. Crucially, dark matter and regular matter are separable.

Comment: I would be tempted to say that, in order to qualify as dark matter, it should be required to be composed of excitions in a fermionic field, since that, roughly, is what defines matter in every other sense I know of. If it were something else, like excitations in a bosonic field, or just a bosonic field having a local mean value that changes, somehow, it should have a different name.

Comment: @SeanE.Lake: Just wanted to say thanks for your patient and thorough answer and replies. I have literally never seen anyone explain dark matter so helpfully to laymen.

Comment: BTW, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter#Composition_of_dark_matter:_baryonic_vs._nonbaryonic) does list modified gravity under dark matter hypotheses. Seems the term is used inconsistently.

Comment: @SeanE.Lake I think that goes a little too far -- at least, it's not how people in the field use the word. For example, "axion dark matter" is quite a popular field of research, but axions are bosonic.

Comment: "The trouble that idea runs into is you're no longer able to explain the bullet cluster, where the gas between the galaxies has collided, but the dark matter and galaxies did not." This line of reasoning suffers from a fundamental logical flaw: given hypotheses A and B, if the predictions of B don't match a specific observation, there is nothing that prevents there from being an unknown hypothesis C that is more correct than A.  For example, given the statements A: 'all swans are white' and B: 'all swans are black', it's easy to point to a white swan and disprove B but A is also false.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, now I feel I'm able to appreciate the concept of dark matter better.

Comment: Is the dark matter hypothesized to be uniformly distributed? If not then shouldn't we be able to detect it's effects this pricing is existence

Comment: @NPranavSubhraveti No, it is not uniform. In fact, we believe that it was over-densities of dark matter that drew ordinary matter to them that caused most (if not all) galaxies to form.

Comment: @knzhou Thanks for that reminder. As you can imagine, I disagree with that usage, and think that such theories should have a different name. Attractive dark fields? Dark bosons? Dark Bose-Einstein condensates? Maybe call the overall phenemona the "(galaxy-scale) over-gravity problem". Dunno - I admit my opinion isn't worth much. :)

Comment: @JimmyJames Reread my post. Where did I even imply that the bullet cluster necessarily implied dark matter? I was pretty careful to point out that it only ruled out modified gravity.

Comment: @SeanE.Lake Of course, I get the distinction you want to draw over 'matter' vs. not matter! At the end of the day, it's all just names anyway.

Comment: "For instance, maybe Newton's law of gravitation is simply wrong on the scale of galaxies and larger. The trouble that idea runs into is you're no longer able to explain" That implies strongly that the bullet cluster proves that Newton's laws of gravitation cannot be incorrect on the scale of galaxies.  Is that not what you meant?

Answer (score 9):

> But the Sun in our solar system also is in the state of plasma and yet doesn't act like a blackbody

Wrong, the sun radiation is approximately fitted as a [black body.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod6.html) The word "black body" does not describe the frequencies, but  the assumption that it absorbs all radiation falling on it and  re-emits it.

[Here is the sun,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunlight#Composition_and_power) and it fits the black body formula approximately.

[image: sunbb]

> Solar irradiance spectrum above atmosphere and at surface. Extreme UV and X-rays are produced (at left of wavelength range shown) but comprise very small amounts of the Sun's total output power.

Plasma is also described by black body radiation.

> so it is possible that the universe in its initial stage also behaved similarly. And this is the reason we find find less baryonic matter than we should. Thus making the concept of dark energy irrelevant.

This is wrong, as seen above because your premiss is wrong, but also, dark matter is necessary to fit the newtonian rotational curves of galaxies, and more observational evidence can be found [in this link.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter#Observational_evidence).

Dark matter is a completely classical observation of newtonian and general relativity. Baryon asymmetry comes from quantum mechanical knowledge of the content of the classical masses, and does not involve dark matter in any meaningful manner.

Comment: The resolution of your picture is too small, I can't read it.

Comment: @Azzinoth sorry, I thought I had given the link. If you click on the image in the link a large version appears